# How can i make back-end for my search-bar in react?

Tags: reactjs, searchbar

I designed a kind of search bar in react, My question is how can i make a back-end for that to show me the content of the website when i type something to looking for it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A way could be, making a node-js API backend. Connect that to a database, and then query that database via the API from the react frontend.

A lot of great tutorials online, about setting up nodejs with mongoDb for example.
https://medium.com/@sssaini/build-a-restful-api-backend-on-mongodb-using-node-js-and-mongoose-63f0866e4603

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need a simple example by some lines code. I am learning.